# A question about zero-sets

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

The set $C(X)$ of all continuous, real-value functions no a topological space $X$ will be provided with an algebraic structure and order structure.

zero-set means:

$Z(f) = Z_{X} (f) = \{ x \in X : f(x) = 0 \} \quad ( f \in C(X) )$

$Z(X)= Z[C(X)]=\{ Z(f) : f \in C(X) \}$

**I know that  $Z(X)$ closed under countable intersection and also  $Z(X)$ need not be closed under infinite union.**

> 1: In a general space, Do countable or finite  union of zero-sets be a
>    zero-set?Why?
>
> 2:Is $Z(X)$ closed under arbitrary intersection?Why?

Comment: What is $Z(X)$?  What does it mean for $Z(X)$ to be, for instance, "closed under countable intersection"?

Comment: @BenW $Z(X)$ is the set of all zero-sets of $X$.

Comment: Hint: Find an example of a closed set that is not a zero set.

Comment: And what does it mean for $Z(X)$ to be closed under countable intersection?

Answer (score 2):

$Z(f)$ is closed under finite unions : $Z(f) \cup Z(g) = Z(fg)$ plus induction.

In general not closed under countable unions: singletons are in $Z(\mathbb{R})$ but $\mathbb{Q}$ is not.

Also $Z(X)$ will not be closed under arbitary intersections, but you need some non-metrisable counterexample (in metric spaces $Z(X)$ is just the collection of all closed sets which *is* closed under all intersections). Think (or search) about a counterexample with some closed set that is not a zero-set.

Comment: What dose it mean? singletons are in $Z(\mathbb{R})$ but $ \mathbb{Q}$ is not.

Comment: @joe the rationals are a countable union of zerosets that’s not a zeroset

Comment: In metric space every closed set is zero-set, buy you say "search about a counterexample with some closed set that is not a zero-set".  I can not see.

Comment: @joe so find a non metric $X$ as an example.

Comment: @joe you can use that in a Tychonoff space all closed sets are intersections of zero-sets. Also, a zero-set is a $G_\delta$ and the reverse holds in normal spaces.